# Angular side bar using ng-sidebar as a component is not working

Tags: angular

I am building a toggle side bar using ng-sidebar which is here
[https://www.npmjs.com/package/ng-sidebar][1]

I builded this inside a component the reason why i am doing this is becose i want to show the toggle side bar only in four pages so i dont want to call the same on root app component.ts

My code for logot.component.ts is like this

```
<ng-sidebar-container>
  <!-- sidebar -->
  <ng-sidebar [opened] = "opened">
    <button (click) = "toggleSidebar()">
      x
    </button>
    <ul class = "menu">
      <li>
        <span (click)="logout()">Logout</span>
      </li>
    </ul>

  </ng-sidebar>

  <div ng-sidebar-content>
    To open the sidebar
    <!-- Page Content -->
    <button (click) = "toggleSidebar()">
      Open sidebar
    </button>

  </div>
</ng-sidebar-container>
```

And the code for logout.component.ts goes here

```
import { Component, OnInit } from '@angular/core';
import {Router} from "@angular/router";

@Component({
  selector: 'app-logout',
  templateUrl: './logout.component.html',
  styleUrls: ['./logout.component.css']
})
export class LogoutComponent implements OnInit {
  opened = false;

  constructor(private router: Router) { }

  ngOnInit(): void {
  }

  logout(){
    console.log('Logout');
    this.router.navigate(['/login']);
  }

  toggleSidebar(){
    this.opened = !this.opened;
  }
}
```

And i am calling this in home like this

```
<app-header></app-header>
<app-logout></app-logout>

  {{ home|json }}
  
<app-footer></app-footer>
```

But the content of the home|json comes after the entire content of app-logout. I have tried in at this way as well

```
<app-header></app-header>
<app-logout>

  {{ home|json }}
  
</app-logout>
<app-footer></app-footer>
```

But this time the home|json is not visible How can i fix this and where i am going wrong? Any idea is really appriciatable.
[1]: https://www.npmjs.com/package/ng-sidebar

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try these changes and add left margin in host component accordingly.

logout.component.html

```
<ng-sidebar-container [class.vh-close]="!opened" [class.vh-open]="opened">
  <!-- sidebar -->
  <ng-sidebar [opened] = "opened">
    <button (click) = "toggleSidebar()">
      x
    </button>
    <ul class = "menu">
      <li>
        <span (click)="logout()">Logout</span>
      </li>
    </ul>

  </ng-sidebar>

  <div ng-sidebar-content>
    <button *ngIf="!opened" (click) = "toggleSidebar()">
      ->
    </button>

  </div>
</ng-sidebar-container>
```

logout.component.css

```
.vh-open {
  height: 100vh;
  width: 20vw;
  z-index: 3;
  position: fixed;
  background-color: aqua;
}

.vh-close {
  height: 100vh;
  z-index: 0;
  position: fixed;
  width: 5vw;
}
```

Comment: Once i have added this everything  works but the problem is that nothing in the host componenet is working here i am sharing the code <app-header></app-header>
`<app-logout></app-logout>
  {{ home|json }}

<app-footer></app-footer>`

Comment: I am not able to press any button or anything after i am adding this.

Comment: Updated the answer. Can you try the given solution.

Answer (score 1):

Haven't used ng-sidebar before, from the [doc](https://github.com/arkon/ng-sidebar), the opened property should be **two-way** binding, try:

```
<ng-sidebar [(opened)]="_opened">
```

Comment: I am using like this only can you show me the full code?